# How Adding Real time data and give min and max angle to Slice Pie chart

Tags: android

I am using Mp chart to show data into pie .But i need to add data to slice dynamically.
e.g If i made 4 slice in pie and want to add value one after the other slice form 0-100 or more then it  how can i do this.If any one know how to achieve this it will be great help for me .
thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!
try to share code or share an reproducible example this could help to find an answer to your issue.

Comment: my requirement  is to create donuts to display progress  i want show multiple download or data receiving from server in  progress on  single pie chart one after the other